# SpringBoot + SpringBatch Clean Install executes Batch Job

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Not sure if anyone else has experienced this, but I created a simple spring boot + spring batch job, and everytime I do a maven clean, install, the batch job runs. Not really what people are looking for, but all my jobs do the same thing.

I followed some threads and you can add a property for:
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
but when I do that the maven clean install works find, but then when you run the main boot file, it doesn't run the job either.

Starting to not like this Boot framework for Spring Batch jobs.

Comment: Can you provide your pom file and the application.properties?

Comment: So you don't like the default that jobs run, and when disabled you are complaining that it doesn't run? Not sure what you want then randomly run and not run the job?

Answer (score 0):

You have a test that is running the Boot application.  The default test from https://start.spring.io will do that.  Remove that test and you should be fine (unless you have any other tests that do launch your Boot application).